# Can't understand this javascript code to paint HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how this code works - I feel like I'm bumping my head against the wall over this:

1. How does initializing the pencil object work? Isn't pencil is a function - how can it be initialized like a class?
2. In the pencil function, what does "this" refer to?
3. In the pencil function, why do I need a separate "tool" variable? I tried removing it and replacing it back with "this", but what happened was the canvas wouldn't listen to mouseup anymore - you click on the canvas, and it just keeps on drawing even if your mouse goes up.
4. Where do the ev._x and ev._y come from? Is this part of the canvas object? Is there documentation I can refer to?
5. What exactly is "layerX" and "offsetX" in the ev_canvas function?
6. Could you help me make sense of the few last lines? I have no idea what they mean, nor have I seen JS written this way.

Thanks!

```
var func = tool[ev.type];
if (func) {
    func(ev);
}
```

Thanks!

```
// Initialize variables
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var tool = new pencil();

function init () {
  // Add listeners
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas);
}

// Pencil tool
function pencil () {
  var tool = this;
  this.started = false;

  // Mousedown
  this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
      tool.started = true;
  };

  // Mousemove
  this.mousemove = function (ev) {
    if (tool.started) {
      context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
      context.stroke();
    }
  };

  // Mouseup
  this.mouseup = function (ev) {
    if (tool.started) {
      tool.mousemove(ev);
      tool.started = false;
    }
  };
}

// Determines mouse position relative to canvas
function ev_canvas (ev) {
  // if (ev.layerX || ev.layerY == 0) { // Firefox
  //   ev._x = ev.layerX;
  //   ev._y = ev.layerY;
  // } else 
  if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
    ev._x = ev.offsetX;
    ev._y = ev.offsetY;
  }

  // Call the event handler of the tool.
  var func = tool[ev.type];
  if (func) {
    func(ev);
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: You really need to focus on one thing at a time. You have 6 different questions here, you should treat them as such. Most of this boils down to "Learn the basics of JavaScript OO" and "Read the documentation for the APIs you're trying to use" though.

Comment: This is far too broad.  Stack Overflow is for asking questions that could be answered in a reasonable amount of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pencil is a class. In JavaScript, class constructors take the form of `function MyClass()`
2. `this` is used to point to the class itself, from within the constructor or member functions. Thus, `this.mouseup()` can be accessed from an instance (in your case) as `tool.mouseup()`
3. Because that's the variable your class uses to keep track of the movement. If you want to replace `tool`, you have to replace the `tool.started` assignments and evaluations as well
4. `ev._x` and `ev._y` are just variables pointing at `ev.offsetX` and `ev.offsetY` which are standard properties of the event object
5. No idea what `layerX` is supposed to be
6. Since the same function is called on all the events (`mousedown`,`mousemove`,`mouseup`), the last function just figures out which event was triggered and calls the appropriate function within your pencil instance (`tool`).

Comment: Not a problem. As others said, though, I suggest you get familiar with the basic concepts and gradually build up from there. It's hard to understand things when you don't have a solid foundation - trust me, I started with jQuery, having no knowledge of JavaScript, and it took me 2 years to understand why some things work the way they do, because I was always confused.

Comment: I'll look into JS OOP next, and build up from there...sometimes, web development lures you into starting to build stuff without really understanding the whole picture because it's lightweight...guess I'll have to start with the fundamentals! Again, thanks for helping out a noobie :)